# continuity of isomorphism of unit circle

Tags: analysis, continuity, differential-topology, inverse-function

I try to show $\mathbb{S}^1\cong[0,1)$, by the map $f(x) = (\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x)$, for $x\in[0,1)$. It's clear that $f$ is continuous and bijective. But I don't know how to show the inverse map $f^{-1}$ is continuous also. Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't.${{}}$

Comment: So what the isomorphic mean here? Just need $f$ to be continuous and bijective?

Comment: Show that $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous by considering what $f^{-1}$ does near the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: We can't say what "isomorphic" means here - you introduced the word in your question. Where did you get it from?

Comment: it's from an introduction to manifold class. The professor never actually mentioned about what "isomorphic" he refers to? I think I should probably ask him. Thanks anyways